# How to avoid nested grouping while extracting numbers (with optional decimal parts) surrounded by spaces?

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to extract numbers (both int and float) from this string:

```
s = 'cs 0  scn /TT0 1 Tf 0.022 Tc -0.022 Tw 11.04 0 0 11.04 108 723.96 Tm (32)Tj 0 Tc 0 Tw 0.946 0 Td ( )Tj 0.021 Tc -0.01 Tw 5.728 0 Td [(I)-1(N)4(TE)3(R)15(M)-2(E)3(D)15(I)-1(A)4(TE)]Tj'
p = r'\s-?\d+(\.\d{1,3})?\s'
```

Since the decimal point will be followed by 1-3 digits, the `\.\d{1,3}` part has to be grouped (i.e., placed within the parantheses) and followed by a `?` since it's optional.

However, using such that regex with `re.findall(p, s)` gives me this:

```
['', '', '.022', '.022', '.04', '', '', '', '', '.946', '.021', '.01', '.728']
```

Only the parts to the right of decimal point are extracted. So, I tried placing the entire number, including the optional decimal part, inside parantheses:

```
p = r'\s(-?\d+(\.\d{1,3})?)\s'
re.findall(p, s)

# Result
>>> [('1', ''), ('0.022', '.022'), ('-0.022', '.022'), ('11.04', '.04'), ('0', ''), ('108', '')]
```

But it returns a list of tuples, where each pair contains the entire match and the decimal part separately.

Further, it fails to match `723.96` which comes right after `108` (which is matched). As far as I can understand, both are surrounded by spaces, but one is matched while the other isn't.

Using `\b` instead of `\s` matches `723.96` but it also matches the numbers in the `[(I)-1(N)4(TE)3(R)15(M)-2(E)3(D)15(I)-1(A)4(TE)]` part of the string. I don't want these to be matched.

Just in case I haven't been clear about my goal, here's the desired output:

```
['0', '1', '0.022', '-0.022', '11.04', '0', '0', '11.04', '108', '723.96', '0', '0', '0.946', '0', '0.021', '-0.01', '5.728', '0']
```

Apart from getting solution to this problem, I'd like to understand the behavior of regex patterns I used.

Comment: Use [`p = r'(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?(?!\S)'`](https://ideone.com/7Rtg9t)

Comment: if that was your desired output, then you needed not to write some complex regex, this simple regex could do the work. import re
s = 'cs 0  scn /TT0 1 Tf 0.022 Tc -0.022 Tw 11.04 0 0 11.04 108 723.96 Tm (32)Tj 0 Tc 0 Tw 0.946 0 Td ( )Tj 0.021 Tc -0.01 Tw 5.728 0 Td [(I)-1(N)4(TE)3(R)15(M)-2(E)3(D)15(I)-1(A)4(TE)]Tj'
p = r'\s([\d.-]+)'

search=re.findall(p,s)
print(search)

Comment: search=re.findall(r'\s([\d.-]+)',s)